# PySide6 - Color specific row with QTableView QAbstractTableModel and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyside, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

This is the first application I have created with Python QT so apologies if I have missed something really fundamental.

The following table is populated via a QAbstractTableModel linked to a Pandas Framework.   I have an PlayerIDX (e.g. 30, who in the example is running 25th) and want that row to be highlighted.   At the moment I have the following function:

```
def highlight_player_row(self, row):
    for column in range(0,self.columnCount()):
        ix = self.index(row, column)
        print(ix)
        self.colors[(row, column)] = QBrush(Qt.darkCyan)
        self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, (Qt.BackgroundRole,))
```

which called with *highlight_player_row(30)* results in the following:

[image]

Rather than row 24/31 being highlighted I would like row 30/25 (marked in yellow).

I don't know if it makes any difference but I am sorting the dataframe prior with:

```
self.idx_data = idx_df.sort_values(by=['CarIdxPosition'])
```

Do I need to go back to where the dataframe is formed from the incoming data and flagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to return the physical position of the sorted DataFrame's *index* :

```
def highlight_player_row(self, row):
    for column in range(0, self.columnCount()):
        ix = self.index(self.idx_data.index.get_loc(row), column) # << here
        self.colors[(row, column)] = QBrush(Qt.darkCyan)
        self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, (Qt.BackgroundRole,))
```

Or ignore the index when sorting and then `highlight_player_row(24)` :

```
self.idx_data = idx_df.sort_values(by=['CarIdxPosition'], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you.   I went with the first suggestion as it maybe keeps model and view separate for now although his might change if I make the table sortable on different columns.    I added a new line: actual_row = self._dataframe.index.get_loc(row) and replaced the two instances of row with actual_row.